# How to send json data with header using volley library

Tags: android, parameters, android-volley

I am trying to send json data to a url in the format below.

```
      {
        “amount”:500,
        “merchant_id”:”104”,
        “narrative”:”John”,
        “reference”:”Steven”
      }
```

To send data to the url, one needs an authorization key as the header, I have already figured out how to set the authorization key as the header in Params, as shown below

```
  @Override
  public Map<String,String >getHeaders()throws AuthFailureError{
  Map<String,String >params=new HashMap<String,String>();
  params.put(“Content-Type”, “text/jsom;);
  params.put(“AuthKey”, Auth);
  return params;
```

but I do not know how to send the data in the particular format shown in the first instance to the url using params with volley. Please help, I am quite new to using Volley library .
This is the rest of code I am currently using it however does not return any response except for an invalid json error. Meaning the format sent is not corresponding to the one desired.

```
   StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(String response) {


         Toast.makeText(Main9Activity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }
 },
         new Response.ErrorListener() {
             @Override
             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 Toast.makeText(Main9Activity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         }){



     @Override
     protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
         HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
         params.put("amount","500");
         params.put("merchant_id", "104");

         params.put("narrative","John");
         params.put("reference", "Steven");



         return params;
     }
     @Override public Map<String,String>getHeaders()throws AuthFailureError{
         Map<String,String>headers=new HashMap<>();
         params.put("Content-Type","text/json");
         params.put("Authorization",Auth);
         return params;
     }
 };
RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Can you please show your current Volley code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Volley post json data to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732699/android-volley-post-json-data-to-server)

Comment: @Vlad none of those show adding headers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send POST request with JSON data using Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley)

Comment: @cricket_007 the question is not about adding header in fact. It already shows how to add header: `I have already figured out how to set the authorization key as the header in Params`

Comment: @cricket_007 I have updated my question to show the current volley code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer below code snipet to post data with custom header in volley.

```
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();

jsonobject.put("amount", "500");
jsonobject.put("merchant_id", "104");
jsonobject.put("narrative", "John");
jsonobject.put("reference", "Steven");

  JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
    Request.Method.POST,url, jsonobject,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            Toast.makeText(Main9Activity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(Main9Activity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    }) {

/**
 * Passing some request headers
 * */
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
     Map<String,String >headers=new HashMap<String,String>();
     headers.put(“Content-Type”, “application/json“);
     headers.put(“AuthKey”, Auth);
     return headers;
}
```

Comment: This method was not successful, the TAG message was empty. Could you show me how to retrive the response in a Toast message, for the record am not as familiar using TAG

Comment: It's just a string variable.You can define any value with it. Like `String TAG = "abcdef"`.

Comment: In that case I did and I received no response, nothing occurred

Comment: @Bwalya I have updated my code to show toast msg. Please check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can send as below:

**The data you want to send:**

```
    Hashmap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("amount", "500");
    data.put("merchant_id", "104");
    data.put("narrative", "John");
    data.put("reference", "Steven");
```

RequestQueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsonobj = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "your url",new JSONObject(data),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    ){

    };
    request.add(jsonobj);
```

Comment: this won't send the JSONObject.

Comment: and this neither will send JSON.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko what issue in this?

Comment: question is `How to send json data ... using volley library`. Your answer does not tell `How to send json data ... using volley library`.