# How to send this JSON POST request in Java using volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

[POST request in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXlYi.jpg)

{"data":["dog",45,256,256,2,5]}

Comment: Better look into this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44732775/15680058
of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732699/android-volley-post-json-data-to-server

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I already tried it but I need to sent this JSON but this isn't in Key-value pair {"data": ["dog",45,256,256,2,5"]}.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think that you First need to create your post request like this: (you will need to change the headers and parameters depending on what you are currently using in your Postman

```java
URL objUrl = new URL("https://hf.space/embed/multimodalart/talentdiffusion/+api/predict/");

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) objUrl.openConnection();

// Setting the request
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoOutput(true);

//add request header (you can add as many as needed
con.setRequestProperty("API-Authorization", "[REPLACE WITH YOU API KEY]");
con.setRequestProperty("[REPLACE WITH HEADER NAME]", "[REPLACE WITH HEADER VALUE]");
// ....

// Setting the data that need to be sent in the body of the request
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
String data = "{\"data\", [\"dog\",45,256,256,2,5\"]}";
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

// Storing the response code in an integer value
int code = con.getResponseCode();

// And if you want to get the api's response you can do this
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
      response.append(inputLine);
     }
in.close();

//Then you do what you want with your response
```

The previous one is a normal way of sending HTTP requests.
Using Volley requests will be something like :

```java
// Create a requestQueue object
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="https://hf.space/embed/multimodalart/talentdiffusion/+api/predict/";
/*JSONObject data = new JSONObject("{\"data\", 
 [\"dog\",45,256,256,2,5\"]}");*/
 // Replace the previous line with these :
 /* {"data":[ "dog",45,256,256,2,5]}*/

JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.put("dog");
arr.put(45);
arr.put(256);
arr.put(256);
arr.put(2);
arr.put(5);

data.put("data", arr);

// Request a response from the api
Stringrequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( Request.Method.POST,
    url,
    data,
    new Response.Listener<String>(){
      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Perform your actions here
      }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          // Perform your events here
       }
    }
);

// Add the request to the queue
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I tried it but I'm getting FileNotFoundException.

Comment: I have changed the JSON input please check.

{"data":["dog",45,256,256,2,5"]}

Previously it was {"data",["dog",45,256,256,2,5"]}

Comment: Hello which method have you used ? The first with HTTPS or the second one with volley ?
Make sure that the string i've put as the URL is the right one and that i didn't miswritten it

Comment: Actually I have noticed that there is a mistake in my way of creating the JSONObject

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you check it please ?

Comment: Thank you @azaLiza I used the second method. It worked for me. I haven't tried your updated answer but tried the previous answer. I just had to change the string inside JSON object and the Headers. It worked. Thanks again